# If in a ring $R$, $x^2=x$ for all $x$ then show that $2x=0$ and $x+y=0$ implies that $x=y$

Tags: ring-theory

If in a ring $R$, $x^2=x$ for all $x$ then show that $2x=0$ and $x+y=0$ implies that $x=y$

Comment: If $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R$, then for $x,y\in R$ we have also $(x+x)^2=x+x$, or
$$x^2+xx+xx+x^2=x+x\implies x+x+x+x=x+x $$
thus $x+x=2x=0$

Comment: Moreover, if $x+y=0$, then $x=x+0=x+2y=x+y+y=0+y=y$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck. BTW, I didn't downvote.